# Signalr Nuget Failing Due To Unrelated Assembly

Tags: signalr

I have some code that I wrote before (which did previously work), which uses SignalR Nuget packages.

There is a client side and a server side project.

I have the following packages installed on the server

```
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="David.Utility.Log4net" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I also have the following BindingRedirects in place in App.Config

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

And this is a screen shot of all the references for the project

[image]

But when I try and attempt to run this process (which is the Server element of the Signalr solution) I get this error:

[image]

I do not get this at all, at the server side process does not even use that Dll. The client side project does, but I am trying to run just the server side process.

Any ideas on this one?